# Running multiple python scripts simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shell

I have a script to start multiple python scripts to run concurrently. But I get this error

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2m
echo "Cohort-1 of wt-1"

echo "starting client 23"
python clients\\client23.py --partition= 1 &
echo "starting client 13"
python clients\\client13.py --partition= 2 &
echo "starting client 37"
python clients\\client37.py --partition= 3 &
echo "starting client 92"
python clients\\client92.py --partition= 4 &
echo "starting client 56"
python clients\\client56.py --partition= 5 &
echo "starting client 17"
python clients\\client17.py --partition= 6 &
echo "starting client 22"
python clients\\client22.py --partition= 7 &
echo "starting client 49"
python clients\\client49.py --partition= 8 &
echo "starting client 58"
python clients\\client58.py --partition= 9 &
echo "starting client 42"
python clients\\client42.py --partition= 10 &

trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM
wait
```

This is the error I get while running the script in command prompt.

```
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.

<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:370: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:374: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe /bin/bash failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return
```

Comment: I think we need more details on what these scripts are doing and which resources they may be racing concurrently for.

Comment: These are client scripts for Federated Learning (FL). A FL server is already running and when these python scripts are triggered they will start the FL training process.